# Nextjs: onChange input not change value on self

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

This is my code:

```
const [defaultBuy, setDefaultBuy] = useState({
    data: '',
    price: 0
})

const changeBuyPrice = (e: any) => {
    let value = e.target.value
    if (value > 1000) {
        value = 9000
    }
    console.log(value)
    setDefaultBuy({...defaultBuy, price: value})
}
```

And this is render:

```
<input defaultValue={defaultBuy.price} name="" type="text" onChange={(e) => changeBuyPrice(e)} />
```

If I put number larger than `1000` in input, `console.log(value)` show me `9000`.

But `<input>` tag not show `9000`.

I want to change `<input>` value also

Comment: try `value={defaultBuy.price}`

Comment: `onChange={(e) => changeBuyPrice(e)}` — creating a new function like that is redundant. Just pass the function you have: `onChange={changeBuyPrice}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the input to reflect the value in the state then you need to make it [a **controlled** component.](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Assign the value in the state to the `value` prop instead of the `defaultValue` prop.

Answer (score 1):

At the end, I did e.target.value = value to update the value of the input field

```
const changeBuyPrice = (e: any) => {
let value = e.target.value
if (value > 1000) {
    value = 9000
}
console.log(value)
setDefaultBuy({...defaultBuy, price: value}) 
e.target.value = value // add this here to update your input field
}
```